# MS Edge CSS animation gets jittery when durations vary

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, microsoft-edge

In the MS Edge browser a simple rotation animation becomes very rough as soon as the animation durations vary. Here's an simple example:

```css
#LogoRotator { z-index: 99; width: 40px; height: 40px; border-radius: 50%; border: 1px solid transparent; border-top-color: #3498db; animation: spin 2s linear infinite; }
#LogoRotator:before { content: ""; position: absolute; top: 2px; left: 2px; right: 2px; bottom: 2px; border-radius: 50%; border: 1px solid transparent; border-top-color: #e74c3c; }
#LogoRotator:after { content: ""; position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 5px; right: 5px; bottom: 5px; border-radius: 50%; border: 1px solid transparent; border-top-color: #f9c922; }
@keyframes spin { 100% { transform: rotate(360deg); } }

#LogoRotator.varySpeed:before { animation: spin 3s linear infinite; }
#LogoRotator.varySpeed:after { animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite; }
```

```html
<p>With identical animation durations:</p>
<div id="LogoRotator"></div>

<p>With different animation durations:</p>
<div id="LogoRotator" class="varySpeed"></div>
```

If you view this snippet in Edge you'll see that when there are identical animation speeds the movement is very smooth, but as soon as the duration changes the movement jumps all over the place:

[image]

Is there a way to make the animation smooth when the duration varies?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by putting overflow: hidden; in #LogoRotator, #LogoRotator:before and #LogoRotator:after